# What is the Mac OSX equivalent of free -m

Tags: macos, memory, terminal

I'm used to typing [`free -m`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/free1.html) in ubuntu to see how much memory is available, in MB.  What's the equivalent command in Mac OSX?

Answer (score 3):

As of 2022, I'd propose this, which I tested on bash and zsh, on Mac 12.2.1:

```
echo $(( $(sysctl -a | awk '/memsize/{print $2}') / 2**30 ))
```

Explanation:

```
$(( ... ))       arithmetic expansion (allows integer math)
awk '/memsize/'  search for memsize in the output
{print $2}       of the output, only print the second "column" of output, i.e., the number
/ 2**30          divide the result by 2 to the 30th power, 1,073,741,824 (i.e., 1 GB)
```

Result on my 16GB Mac:

```
16
```

Answer (score 1):

Since OS X is BSD-based, your best bet will be using `sysctl` to get the information you need.

```
sysctl -a | awk '/hw./' && '/mem/'
```

You could also try this:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/is-there-a-mac-os-x-terminal-version-of-the-free-command-in-linux-systems

Comment: Thanks, that's close, the other question has some good suggestions.

Comment: That is absolutely not correct. Executing that would try to execute `/mem/`, which is nonsense, after successful pipeline evaluation. Did you mean `sysctl -a | awk '/hw\.mem/'` ?

Comment: Since SO bans less than two character edits (a disputable decision btw), I leave this as a comment: `sysctl -a | awk '/hw./ && /mem/'` : `/mem/` shall be a part of the `awk` filter.

On a separate note, it is a bad bad bad idea to post something you read on the Internet untested. However, the gist of the suggestion stands and is pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

should be :

```
sysctl -a | awk '/hw./' && '/mem/'
```

(note the `'/mem/'`)

then run the output through `egrep` (depending upon what is desired).

There are some `perl` scripts too - on the net.

Comment: Firstly, one shall try shell commands before posting -- in this case, one would see that ` && '/mem/'` shall instead be a part of the awk filter, like this: `sysctl -a | awk '/hw./ && /mem/'` ; and secondly, why on Earth would one want to have an additional `egrep` filter when `/hw./` and `/mem/` already _are_ regexp expressions, and one can simply add as many as one prefers the same way via `awk`?